# HTTP post not working on flutter to API Laravel

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm new to flutter and I having problem with using Flutter and Laravel as API Backend.
I'm using Android Studio and Emulator from Android Studio.
I don't know what is the problem with it. I don't know if because it didn't connect to the API or there's something wrong with my code.

I have trying using postman to integrate by making response post to the API and everything work fine but in the flutter it just keep failing.

Can someone help me?
This is the code
LoginPage.dart

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {

  @override   _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState(); }

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {   final TextEditingController _nimController = new TextEditingController();   final TextEditingController _passwordController = new TextEditingController();   bool isLoading = false;

  @override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget loadingIndicator = isLoading
        ? Container(
            color: Colors.black26,
            width: double.infinity,
            height: double.infinity,
            child: indicatorLoad(),
          )
        : Container();

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: PaletteColor.primarybg,
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          SafeArea(
            child: Center(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(24),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        child: Image.asset(
                          'assets/images/simbasaLogo2.png',
                          width: 230,
                        ),
                      ),
                      MainForms(
                        nimFilter: _nimController,
                        passwordFilter: _passwordController,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.topRight,
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 16),
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {},
                          child: Text(
                            "Forgot password?",
                            style: TypographyStyle.caption2.merge(
                              TextStyle(
                                color: PaletteColor.primary,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      ButtonLogin(
                        onPressedFunction,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            child: loadingIndicator,
            alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );   }

  savePrefFungsion(String nama) async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setBool(GlobalKeySharedPref.keyPrefIsLogin, true);
    prefs.setString(GlobalKeySharedPref.keyPrefUsername, _nimController.text);   }

  void onPressedFunction() async {
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });

    bool isLogin = await AuthLogin.auth(username: _nimController.text, password: _passwordController.text);

    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });

    if (isLogin) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => DashboardPage(
            username: " ", //element["UserName"],
          ),
        ),
      );
      //savePrefFungsion(element["FullName"]);
    }
    //});

    if (!isLogin)
      showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            content: Text("Username or Password is Wrong"),
          );
        },
      );   } }
```

This is the API response code
AuthLogin.dart

```
class AuthLogin{
  static auth({@required String username, @required String password}) async{
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    try {
      final response = await http.post(Uri.parse('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/auth/login'),
       headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
       body: {
        "email" : username,
        "password" : password
      });

      print("reponse : " + response.body);

      Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(response.body);

      if(data["access_token"] != null){
        pref.setString("auth_token", data["access_token"]);
        pref.setBool("is_login", true);
        return true;
      }

      return false;
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

and I have try

```
class AuthLogin{
      static auth({@required String username, @required String password}) async{
        SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        try {
         final response = await http.get(Uri.http('127.0.0.1:8000', '/api/v1/auth/login'),
           headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
           body: {
            "email" : username,
            "password" : password
          });
    
          print("reponse : " + response.body);
    
          Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(response.body);
    
          if(data["access_token"] != null){
            pref.setString("auth_token", data["access_token"]);
            pref.setBool("is_login", true);
            return true;
          }
    
          return false;
        } catch (e) {
          print(e);
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
```

still the same

In postman login success with email and password but in the flutter running app always response back with "Username or Password is Wrong" even though the email and password are correct.

Btw I'm using flutter sdk 2.0.0 Just pointing out.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Firstly can you confirm if you are using emulator or simulator or a physical device for you testing

Comment: can you also check maybe this part `catch (e) { print(e); return false;  }` is printing an error

Comment: Hello, I'm using emulator that provide from android studio. I will update in on  my post

Comment: if you are using emulator 127.0.0.1 won't work on emulator try changing it to 10.0.2.2:8000 and retest it

Comment: that means you will have something like this `Uri.parse('http://10.0.2.2:8000/api/v1/auth/login')` in your AuthLogin class instead of `Uri.parse('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/auth/login')`

Comment: Hello for some reason the print(e) doesn't show anything about the response of api. But i will trying changing the http

Comment: does that mean in Laravel I need to change DB_HOST to 10.0.2.2 to?

Comment: No you don't need to change anything in Laravel just update your AuthLogin and retest it

Comment: I already changing to 10.0.2.2 still not working.

Comment: okay did you see anything in your log

Comment: can you add the picture of your new AuthLogin class as well